# Limit data types to be inserted into a QTableWidget using PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I want to build a QTableWidget of 3 columns that can be edited in place by the user with the following scheme:

- First column: string
- Second column: float
- Third column: integer

I would like to avoid the user to insert data types different to what I have specified.
I'd like to have something similar to the `setValidator` of the QLineEdit.

How can I do that without doing post-mortem validation?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: place QLineEdits as cell widgets of QTableWidget